# print the number which is present in documentA but absent in documentB

Tags: perl

I've a problem in making a Perl program for matching the numbers in two documents. Let's say there are documents A and B.

So I want to have the numbers which is present in document A and absent in the document B.

Example 1:

DocA: 1 2 3 5 6  8 9 10 11 12 13

DocB: 1 2 3 6 7 8 9 10 11

output:

5 12 13

**EDITED:**

```
@a=qw( 1 2 3 5 6  8 9 10 11 12 13);
@b=qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11);
@new=();
@new1=();
for($i=0;$i<=$#a;$i++)
{
  for($j=0;$j<=$#b;$j++)
  {
    if($a[$i] ne $b[$j])
    {
      push(@new,$b[$j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the above is the program i ve written , but unable to get tne answer, how to rectify the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CPAN module Array::Utils. The following will do what you need:

```
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @a = qw( 1 2 3 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13);
my @b = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11);

my @diff = array_minus(@a, @b);`
```

By the way, the reason your program does not work is because you made a logic error. You are adding a value to @new EVERY TIME the value does not match. So, in the first iteration of the loop you compare the a value to the b value. Even though the value is equal to the first element of @b, it is not equal to the other ten elements of @b and hence all of these elements are added to @new. I have rewritten your loop. Note the more Perlish loops instead of the C-loop you used in your code.

```
my @a = qw( 1 2 3 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13);
my @b = qw( 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 11);
my @new = ();

for my $a_value (@a) {
    my $b_not_in_a = 1;
    INNER: for my $b_value (@b)
    {   if($a_value == $b_value)    {
        $b_not_in_a = 0;
        last INNER;     }
    }

    if ($b_not_in_a)
    {
        push(@new,$a_value);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~nedkonz/Algorithm-Diff-1.15/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash. Read DocA and initialize a hash using the read numbers as keys:

```
open(INPUT, "DocA");
while (<INPUT>)
{
   chomp;
   $myhash{$_} = 1;
}
```

Then read DocB and foreach number, check if already defined in your hash:

```
open(INPUT, "DocB");
while (<INPUT>)
{
   chomp;
   if (not defined $myhash{$_})
   {
      print "$_\n";
   }
}
```

- This code asumes you have a number per line. If your files are formatted differently, you will need to adapt it.
- This code will work even if your numbers aren't ordered.

Answer (score 0):

The lists in your example are sorted. I am assuming that they are, and that you're not allowed to use modules since it is homework. Also, since it is homework, I won't give the answer, but some hints in the right direction.

If you would do this by hand, and you are only allowed to look at the front of each row, how would you do it? If the head of A is a number smaller than B, what does that mean? If it is equal, what does that mean? If it is larger, what does that mean?

Now you know how you can handle one situation, from that you can create some kind of step to reduce the problem. Now define when you need to stop, and what the possible leftovers of the lists are at that point, and how you can get your answer from the values you collected in the step, and the remainder after you stop.

Some examples of extreme cases:

```
@a = qw();
@b = qw(1 2 3);

@a = qw (1 2 3);
@b = qw (4 5 6);

@a = qw(1  3  5);
@b = qw(2 4 6)
```

Good luck!